# Securing REST API using GRAILS, GROOVY, ORACLE with API KEY

Tags: security, grails, groovy, spring-security, api-key

I have a naive question.
I am looking for some web application that implements Authentication and Authorization mechanism using api keys.

```
Example Case: Users authenticate themselves using an api key (apikey generation 
mechanism is either GOOGLE or any other free service). The logic identify the user along 
with the provided apikey and release resource access delegation accordingly]
```

For me the optimal case is to use Grails framework with oracle database.

Is there any web application for that?, otherwise how would I follow step by step to accomplish it?

Comment: Please limit your question to a specific problem. SO is not about recommendations

Answer (score 0):

I would do a search on the Grails plugin site for oauth plugins:
http://plugins.grails.org/

Look at what they offer, and maybe look at the code to see how you can extend them to get what you want.

I would also take a look at the Spring Security Rest plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on authentication methods that you're using. I suppose in order to secure REST APIs, you can probably write a filter/interceptor to check against any third party auth that you desire. I reckon that you're probably having the idea of using JWT authentication for this, right?